# Smooth color grading given start and end color

Tags: graphics, colors

What is the best way to control color grading having a start and an end color? Using RGB or HSV ?

E.g
.

```
step = 1/nrColors;
currStep = 0;

for i = 1:nrColors

   p = sigmoid(currStep);

   R = start.R * p + end.R * (1-p)
   G = ...
   B = ...

currStep = currStep + step ;
end
```

or

```
   H = start.H * p + end.R * (1-p)
   S = ...
   V = ...
```

With neither of the above, I could achieve a good transtion (either the colors are too tight to each other, or the colors are not smooth from humans point of view).

Where could I find a good reference on the subject ?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you will get the best match to human perception if you interpolate in the "Lab" color space:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB

Also, a sigmoid interpolation may be appropriate if you are animating a color transition, but if you are displaying a sequence of swatches that smoothly interpolate from one color to another (which is what it sounds like given that you talk about them being too tight to each other), then you might just want to interpolate linearly. Otherwise the start and end colors will be very similar, and the center ones more spaced out.